# Snowflake: Can't use the stage (S3) - SQL compilation error: Stage does not exist or not authorized

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I create an external stage in Snowflake via (I've tried with a public bucket too)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE stage "DATABASE"."SCHEMA"."STAGE_NAME"
    url='s3://bucket'
    CREDENTIALS=(AWS_KEY_ID='xxxxxxxxxxxx' AWS_SECRET_KEY='xxxxxxxxxxxx');
```

I could view the parameters of this stage via

```
SHOW STAGES

DESC STAGE "DATABASE"."SCHEMA"."STAGE_NAME"
```

However, I'm getting the error whenever I'm trying to interact with this stage (e.g., LIST @STAGE_NAME or load a file).

```
SQL compilation error: Stage 'DATABASE.SCHEMA.STAGE_NAME' does not exist or not authorized.
```

I've tried different snowflake roles but can't make it work. Could anyone point me where to look? Perhaps I have to assign any permissions to the stage?

Answer (score 0):

You have STAGE-privileges: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-access-control-privileges.html#stage-privileges

For COPY, LIST and others you need the privileges mentioned there. (USAGE, READ and maybe WRITE)

Comment: Thank you for getting back, Marcel.
As far as I understand, COPY, LIST, etc., privileges could be only assigned to an internal stage. For the external one, there is only the USAGE privilege available. I've granted the USAGE privilege to the stage and the schema this stage belongs to. However, this did help to go past the error message.

Comment: You also need to give USAGE on the database

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty weird, but I can list a stage if the name consists of capital letters. No additional permissions are needed.

Works fine

```
CREATE OR REPLACE stage "DATABASE"."SCHEMA"."STAGE_NAME"
    url='s3://bucket'
    CREDENTIALS=(AWS_KEY_ID='xxxxxxxxxxxx' AWS_SECRET_KEY='xxxxxxxxxxxx');
```

```
LIST @STAGE_NAME
```

Returns Stage does not exist or not authorized.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE stage "DATABASE"."SCHEMA"."Stage_Name"
    url='s3://bucket'
    CREDENTIALS=(AWS_KEY_ID='xxxxxxxxxxxx' AWS_SECRET_KEY='xxxxxxxxxxxx');
```

```
LIST @Stage_Name
```

At the same time, I see all Stages while running the "SHOW STAGES" command.

Are there any constraints on the naming? I haven't found any so far.

Comment: Did you grant Ussge on the database itself?

Comment: Hi Robert.
There are the following permissions for the Role I use. DATABASE: USAGE; SCHEMA: USAGE, MODIFY, CREATE STAGE.
With these permissions, I could create stages and view them via SHOW STAGES. But could only LIST parameters of the stage that has no lower case letters in the name.

Answer (score 0):

If the stage DDL has the name enclosed in double-quotes(CREATE OR REPLACE stage "DATABASE"."SCHEMA"."STAGE_NAME"), the name becomes case-sensitive which is why you cannot see it. Do not enclose the stage name in quotes and you should be able to see it regardless of the case.
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-stage.html#required-parameters