# SQL compilation error: Stage 'MANAGE_DB.EXTERNAL_STAGES.AWS_STAGE' does not exist or not authorized

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to load data using COPY command.

```
COPY INTO DATA_S.PUBLIC.ORDERS
    FROM @MANAGE_DB.external_stages.aws_stage
    file_format= (type = csv field_delimiter=',' skip_header=1)
    pattern='.*Order.*';
```

Unfortunately I am getting the following message.

> "SQL compilation error: Stage 'MANAGE_DB.EXTERNAL_STAGES.AWS_STAGE' does not exist or not authorized.

Comment: this error means the stage does not exist or you are not authorized to use it. if you know it exists it sounds like a permission problem, does your role have permission, or do you need to swap to another role which does have permission?

Comment: I think AmazonS3FullAccess is the role permission. Am I right? I swapped roles it did not work.

Comment: permission is a snowflake permission.. This other question is very similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70892374/snowflake-cant-use-the-stage-s3-sql-compilation-error-stage-does-not-exis

Comment: Simeon, I am not quite understanding the role permissions. Can you please elaborate it? When I load data using copy command now I am getting the following message: "Copy executed with 0 files processed."

Comment: well you no, longer have a snowflake permissions problem, with that new result. Now you ether have a problem with you pattern matching on the stage files, or the path.

Comment: I would use the LIST command to see what files snowflake can see: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/list.html

Comment: I did try LIST @aws_stage; command. I can see the Order file. But it is not loading.

Comment: so that implies you have a pattern problem. what is the full name of the file? it seems you pattern is valid compared to https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html#loading-using-pattern-matching but you do not have a file extension on you file.